# .Net Core API with Redis on Kubernetes cluster(minikube)

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, redis, asp.net-core-webapi, minikube

I have implemented a .Net Core API which is caching and accessing the data from Redis cache. I have created images for API and Redis and deployed both of them on 2 different pods. Currently I am using minikube as a Kubernetes cluster on my local machine.

.Net API code:

Controller method code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var cacheKey = "weatherList";
            var rng = new Random();
            IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> weatherList = new List<WeatherForecast>();
            var redisWeatherList = _distributedCache.Get(cacheKey);
            if (redisWeatherList != null)
            {
                var serializedWeatherList = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(redisWeatherList);
                weatherList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WeatherForecast>>(serializedWeatherList);
                return Ok(new Tuple<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>, string>(weatherList, "Data fetched from cache"));
            }
            else
            {
                weatherList = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                }).ToArray();

                var serializedWeatherList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weatherList);
                redisWeatherList = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedWeatherList);
                var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetAbsoluteExpiration(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5));
                _distributedCache.Set(cacheKey, redisWeatherList, options);
                return Ok(new Tuple<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>(weatherList));
            }
        }
```

Redis cache configuration in the Startup class

```
        services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration").GetSection("RedisConfiguration").Value;
        });
```

For deployment I have created the deployment and service yaml files for both of them. Since we have to access the API so its type is selected as LoadBalancer and Redis will be interacted by the API type is selected as default ClusterIP.

YML files:
API YML files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
  labels:
    app: api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api-deployment
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: appsettings-volume
          configMap:
            name: appsettings-configmap
      containers:
        - name: api-deployment
          image: testapiimage
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts: 
            - name: appsettings-volume
              mountPath: /app/appsettings.json
              subPath: appsettings.json
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 200m
              memory: 200Mi

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-service
  labels:
    app: api-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: api-deployment
```

---

Redis YML files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-deployment
  labels:
    app: redis-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis-deployment
        image: redis
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 200Mi

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-service
  labels:
    app: redis-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis-deployment
```

Now the issue and confusion is how API will know how to connect to the ClusterIP of Redis pod. In the local code it is connecting through localhost. Therefore, while API container is running it is still trying to connect to the Redis container through localhost only just like in code.

Is there any way that the API container will automatically connected to the ClusterIP of the Redis container like Environment variables but in my case I have to depend on the value of Redis host which in the container environment is the ClusterIP which is not static and cant be injected through appsettings.

Please guide me here.

Comment: Have you tried Redis service endpoint (redis-service.default.svc.local.com:6379)? You could use configmap to configure it

Answer (score 0):

To reach other pods in the cluster that are not exposed publicly, you can use the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) assigned by the Kubernetes internal DNS. Kubernetes internal DNS will resolve this to the necessary ClusterIP value to reach the service.

The FQDN is in the format:

```
<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.<cluster-domain>
```

The default value of the cluster-domain is cluster.local and if no namespace was provided to redis, it will be running in the default namespace.

Assuming all defaults, the FQDN of the redis service would be:
`redis-service.default.svc.cluster.local`.

Kubernetes will automatically resolve this to the appropriate ClusterIP address.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/